# Build.PRODUCT for Nook and Kindle Fire devices

Tags: android, kindle-fire, nook

I want to port an existing Android application to Nook and Kindle Fire devices. I want to turn off unsupported features by querying for android.os.Build.PRODUCT and android.os.Build.MODEL codes.
Could someone provide me with the various Build.PRODUCT and Build.MODEL codes for these devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I should have googled for specs, not for Build.Product. I found them here and here:

https://nookdeveloper.barnesandnoble.com/product/nook-device-specs.html

https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/specifications.html

To query for the MANUFACTURER would be a better option, since you are ready for new devices, but as far as I know, this works only for the Kindle Fire devices, as these have Amazon as the Manufacturer, while Nook devices have Foxconn. But Foxconn might have manufactured other devices, right?